# how to drag and drop textfields in pdf Using React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to build a react js app that renders the pdf. In that pdf user can drag the text and drop the same text anywhere on the file. Also, user can type on the pdf wherever he wants.

Anyone know any clue how to do this.

I am trying some library to read pdf but they are not providing the feature of editing and dragging text.

Anyone know any npm which spot Reacts??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't edit directly the pdf, you need to read the content of the pdf > render it on a blank page > edit it (drag and drop fields) > transform the whole content back to pdf.

Comment: I need to build the app something like HelloSign(https://www.hellosign.com/?utm_medium=cpc&utm_source=google&utm_campaign=HS-Brand-US&utm_content=hs-brand-us_hello-sign&utm_term=hello%20sign&utm_matchtype=e&gclid=Cj0KCQjws-OEBhCkARIsAPhOkIby-_QYCCf6wrjKzTEp7lIO3F62tbh_4HI1NsXrHQqLlIrekxX9fvAaAvlnEALw_wcB)

Comment: @mehak do you find solution for same?